# Navigator.push not working as its supposed to be

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to go to the LoginScreen from my StartScreen but it does not work when I click on the elevated button

```
PersonStatus(
              label: 'EMPLOYER',
              imageProvider: 'assets/images/employer.png',
              onPressed: (context) {
                int employerNum = 1;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                        employerNumber: employerNum,
                      ),
                    ));
              },
            ),
```

Following is the LoginScreen

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int employerNumber;
  const LoginScreen({Key? key, required this.employerNumber}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          PersonStatus(
              label: widget.employerNumber == 1 ? 'EMPLOYER' : 'EMPLOYEE',
              imageProvider: widget.employerNumber == 1
                  ? 'assets/images/employer.png'
                  : 'assets/images/employee.png'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Although I passed some parameters forward I expected it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the Person Status where in the paramaters you have used "onPressed", I think you have not written that part correctly(meaning you have to define your custom function). that is why it is not working.. try changing it so share that part of code(Person Status) so I can suggest some workaround. If anything works in that part kindly upvote and do share your mistake ;)

Comment: Yes, the problem was over there, I used `final Function onpressed` instead of  `final Function() onPressed`, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are passing the wrong context to the navigator, try removing the context parameter in the onpressed:

```
PersonStatus(
              label: 'EMPLOYER',
              imageProvider: 'assets/images/employer.png',
              onPressed: () {
                int employerNum = 1;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                        employerNumber: employerNum,
                      ),
                    ));
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Please I have tried but still not working

Comment: @Samuel Can you try with a basic scaffold? Just to try to eliminate possible errors. So please change your code to `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Scaffold())` and tell me what happend
                    )

Comment: Still not working sir

Answer (score 0):

You can create callback for PersonStatus:

```
PersonStatus(
              Function(int result) onTap// it's a callback
              label: 'EMPLOYER',
              imageProvider: 'assets/images/employer.png',
              onPressed: (context) {
                int employerNum = 1;
                onTap(employerNum);
              },
            )
```

and then use it:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int employerNumber;
  const LoginScreen({Key? key, required this.employerNumber}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          PersonStatus(
              label: widget.employerNumber == 1 ? 'EMPLOYER' : 'EMPLOYEE',
              imageProvider: widget.employerNumber == 1
                  ? 'assets/images/employer.png'
                  : 'assets/images/employee.png',
            onTap: (result) {
               Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                    employerNumber: employerNum,
                  ),
                ));

            },),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```